# How do i split this in python?

Tags: python

lets say that there was a table with the following contents:

```
<td>Dog,Cat,Mouse</td>
<td>Snake,Dragon,Dinosaur,Lizard</td>
<td>Owl,Falcon,Phoenix</td>
```

and i want to make it like this on python:

```
>>>pets
[['Dog'],['Cat'],['Mouse'],['Snake'],['Dragon'],['Dinosaur'],['Lizard'],['Owl'],['Falcon'],['Phoenix']]
```

This is what i have managed so far.

```
animal = table.find_all('td')
pets = []
for i in animal:
    a = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',str(i))
    pets.append(a)
```

however, i cant figure out a way to turn

```
['Dog','Cat','Mouse']
```

to

```
['Dog'],['Cat'],['Mouse'],
```

and so on. please help. This is my first few days of programming and im already stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is an [xy problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) - why should every element be nested in its own list? Why not just use a flat list of values?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
strs = """<td>Dog,Cat,Mouse</td>
<td>Snake,Dragon,Dinosaur,Lizard</td>
<td>Owl,Falcon,Phoenix</td>"""

r = re.compile(r'<td>(.*?)</td>')
print [[x] for m in r.finditer(strs) for x in m.group(1).split(',')]
```

This prints:

```
[['Dog'], ['Cat'], ['Mouse'], ['Snake'], ['Dragon'], ['Dinosaur'], ['Lizard'], ['Owl'], ['Falcon'], ['Phoenix']]
```

And supports multiple `<td>..</td>` on the same line.

Comment: @bernardpaulus it could fail for `'<td><td>Owl,Falcon,Phoenix</td></td>'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudary Yep, but that input is much less likely than a `<td>Dog,Cat,Mouse</td><td>Snake,Dragon,Dinosaur,Lizard</td>` on the same line. Since the modification is essentially one character (the addition of a `?` after the `*` in your regex), I thought it would be interesting.

Furthermore, your regex, `r'<td>(.*)</td>'`, does not support the case you point out. But hah, well, good answer anyway :)

Comment: @bernardpaulus I think you've a good point, I rolled back to your edit. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that `regex` (regular expressions) are not always the best solution to parse some data. Here for instance, all your elements are separated by a `,` so the `split` method is the way to go.

As for putting your elements as arrays with a single element, list comprehension is the easiest way to do it.
Again: make sure you **really** want/need to do this. It doesn't make much sense to have a set of lists with a single element.

Here's a suggested implementation:

```
elements = table.find_all('td')
pets = []
for e in elements:
    # The following line is only needed if 'find_all' keeps the <td> and </td>
    e_tagless = e[5:len(e)-5]

    animals = e_tagless.split(',')
    pets += [ [animal] for animal in animals ]
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning not to use regex for something this simple. Could be improved by questioning the need of appending each animal into it's own list.

Comment: Actually I already did that by asking him (her?) if that's what he really wants to do. I'll edit the answer so it's clearer.

Comment: That's still better than giving him a regex solution. ;) But good job changing it :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> my_list = ['Dog','Cat','Mouse'] 
>>> map(lambda x: [x], my_list)
[['Dog'], ['Cat'], ['Mouse']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
animal = table.find_all('td')
    pets = []
    for i in animal:
       a = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',str(i))
       pets.append(a)
```

To this:

```
animal = table.find_all('td')
    pets = []
    for i in animal:
       a = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',str(i))
       pets.append([a])
```

You were just missing the two characters `[]` when you were appending to mark up each item into it's own list during the loop iteration.